# unknown variable 'general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using MySQL / 10.1.29-MariaDB-6 on Kali Linux 2018 VM.

I have the following entry in mariadb.cnf, mysql.cnf, and 50-server.cnf.

```
general_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log         = 1
```

The conf file shows that the following config files are used to determine options:

The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:

1. `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf` (this file) to set global defaults,
2. `/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf` to set global options.
3. `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf` to set MariaDB-only options.
4. `~/.my.cnf` to set user-specific options.

Logging IS working to the file specified, but whenever I try to type the following mysql command, I am met with the following error:

```
root@kali:/var/log/mysql# mysql -u root -p

mysql: unknown variable 'general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What is "the mysql command" that you type which causes the error?

Comment: Elenst, updated question to include the command followed by the error.

Comment: Try to put quotes  `general_log_file    ="/var/log/mysql/mysql.log"` to see if it works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the **sections** of the config file(s) where `general_log_file` option is set. It must be `[mysqld]`, or `[server]`, or `[mariadb]` and alike, but it must not be `[mysql]` or `[client]` or alike. `general_log_file` is a server-only option.

Comment: Very good Elenst. I removed the general_log_file options from all config files except for  /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf, and it now is logging properly and mysql is operational. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks! I searched for the solution for about 2 hours! I tried to change ft_min_word_len in mariadb and in my.cnf file and it didn't work. What I had to do was changing this attribute in mariadb-server.cnf.